# iOS: Show local notification content text with the screen locked

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

I have to send a very basic local notification when the app is running in the background.

When the screen is locked, the notification content text is hidden.

Is there a way to trigger a local notification and show the text even when the screen is locked?

Comment: This is something that the user controls through the settings for your app - They can select to show notification previews always, when unlocked (the default) or never.

Comment: I want something similar to that, is it possible to do it programmatically?

Comment: No, it is under user control